# Is it haram or makruh to unwittingly watch a video about a math "magic trick"?

Tags: halal-haram

Al Salam Alaykum. I was going through some QI clips on youtube and one had a title of " [celebrity name] mathmagician." I thought it would be a great math feat but at the end of the video it turned out to be one of those math tricks where if you follow some steps with any starting number, you always end up at the same answer. This leads me to ask, is watching such a video haram (especially without preemptively guessing that it involved 'tricks')?

I read before that pursuing or watching magic tricks stops you from getting good deeds from your salah for forty days.

This question seems absolutely silly. But given the big consequence, I just want to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magic or *Sihr* in Islamic tradition is the act of summoning help from jin , which is considered a major sin and requires quite an un-Islamic procedure to go through with it .

**THIS** type of magic however is simply a bunch of slight of hand accompanied by mathematical or physics tricks , it hardly lives up to the Islamic definition .

So when you read something about magic in Islam , do keep in mind what type of magic we are talking about .

**So to answer your question** : No , that isn't the magic meant by this hadith .

Comment: Jazakom Allah Khayran @SongBird for letting me know what magic is when it comes to Islam. I'm relieved to know that I didn't do something haram.

Comment: @Khaled all the best to you my friend .